# Creating a grouped bar plot in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I have a data frame df in R, that looks like this:

```
        D     C     B     E     K     R
Rd      80    80    80    80    80    80
Sw      100   100   100   100   100   100
Sf      100   100   100   100   100   100
```

I'm trying to plot the data in a bar plot. I need the y axis to have the range 0-100, and the x axis to be the category names. Basically, I need it to look like this:

```
100 |               _ _ _ _ _ _    _ _ _ _ _ _
    |_ _ _ _ _ _   | | | | | | |  | | | | | | |
    | | | | | | |  | | | | | | |  | | | | | | |
    | | | | | | |  | | | | | | |  | | | | | | |
    | | | | | | |  | | | | | | |  | | | | | | |
 0  |_|_|_|_|_|_|__|_|_|_|_|_|_|__|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
     D C B E K R    D C B E K R    D C B E K R
         Rd             Sw            Sf
```

With all of the Ds the same color, all of the Cs the same colour, and so on.

I'm not sure how to do this, or which libraries to use.

So far I have:

```
counts <- as.matrix(df$D, df$C, df$B, df$E, df$K, df$R)

barplot(counts, beside = TRUE, space = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), xlab = "",
col = c("coral", "coral1", "coral2", "coral3", "coral4", "cornflowerblue"),
    names.arg = c("D", "C", "B", "E", "K", "R"))
mtext(side = 1, text = "x label", line = 7)
```

But it only displays something like this:

```
100 |  _ _   _ _
    |_| | |_| | |
    | | | | | | |
    | | | | | | |
    | | | | | | |
 0  |_|_|_|_|_|_|_
     D C B E K R
       x label
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting only this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df2 <- t(as.matrix(df))
bp <- barplot(df2,beside=TRUE,col=1:6)
mtext(rownames(df2),1,at=bp)
```

[image]

If you would like to edit things to spin axis labels or exactly position the group/bar labels, then you can do something like the below code. Change the `line=` arguments to affect the vertical position of the labels and the `las=1` argument on the `barplot` call to spin the labels as required.

```
df2 <- t(as.matrix(df))
bp <- barplot(df2,beside=TRUE,col=1:6,axisnames=FALSE,las=1)
mtext(rownames(df2),1,at=bp,line=0.6)
mtext(colnames(df2),1,at=colMeans(bp),line=2)
```

Comment: By doing it this way: `df2 <- t(as.matrix(df))`
`bp <- barplot(df2, beside = TRUE, col = 1:6, names.arg = c("D", "C", "B", "E", "K", "R", "D", "C", "B", "E", "K", "R", "D", "C", "B", "E", "K", "R"))`
`mtext(rownames(df2), 1, at = bp)` I am only able to display the letters, and not the Rd, Sw, and Sf. Is there a way to display these too?

Comment: @user3043867 - what do you mean? You can clearly see my example has both sets of labels!

Comment: Is there also a way to display the actual values in the barplot?

Answer (score 4):

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(groups = rep(c("Rd", "Sw", "Sf"), each=6),
                 bars = rep(c("D", "C", "B", "E", "K", "R"), 3),
                 values = sample(1:100,18))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=bars, y=values, fill=bars)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~groups, ncol=3)
```

Result: see the figure below.

Or, if you take the data frame from the question:

```
df <- read.table(sep=" ", header=T, text="
D C B E K R
Rd 80 80 80 80 80 80
Sw 100 100 100 100 100 100
Sf 100 100 100 100 100 100")

df$facet <- row.names(df)
library(reshape2)
df.long <- melt(df, "facet")
ggplot(df.long, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~facet, ncol=3)
```

[image]

Comment: reshape2 is the way to go for such issues. Ideally, each data point should have its own line in the data frame (long format). This is achieved by the melt command in the reshape2 package.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't want that as.matrix call with the column vectors from the data.frame -- it is most likely that you want: as.matrix(D), for instance:

```
barplot(as.matrix(data.frame(rpois(10, 2), rpois(10, 1))), beside = T)
```

Basically, I am giving a simple example, imagine you have:

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,3,4))
```

you were doing as.matrix(df$x, df$y) - that's not what you want, you want to do: as.matrix(df), thus:

```
barplot(as.matrix(df), beside = T)
```

will give you what you want. The key is to look at what "as.matrix" does.