# Stack bar plot in Rof non-numeric data?

Tags: r

I have the below data in a data.frame

```
Count   Group A Group B
2   Red One 
1   Blue    One 
1   Green   One 
5   Red Two
1   Blue    Two
2   Red Three
4   Blue    Three
2   Green   Three
1   Yellow  Three
```

I need to plot this in a way similar to this
[image]

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `?xtabs` to create a frequency table on `count` and `?barplot` with `beside=TRUE` set to get your barplot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a grouped bar plot in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985284/creating-a-grouped-bar-plot-in-r)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, these bars are not stacked.

Comment: Jonathan I tried it, but this is slightly different cause entries in the examples are all numeric, but I have non-numeric groups. So it  gave me Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: this is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210152/plotting-grouped-bar-charts-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading in your data;

```
df <- read.table(text="Count Group_A Group_B
2 Red One
1 Blue One
1 Green One
5 Red Two
1 Blue Two
2 Red Three
4 Blue Three
2 Green Three
1 Yellow Three", sep=" ", header=TRUE)
```

Specifying the level ordering of factors;

```
df$Group_A <- factor(df$Group_A, levels=c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"))
df$Group_B <- factor(df$Group_B, levels=c("One", "Two", "Three"))
```

Creating a barplot;

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Group_B, y=Count, fill=Group_A), position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Red"="red", "Blue"="blue", "Green"="green","Yellow"="yellow"))
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want the uneven groups to have different widths, I'd add in the missing data;

```
df <- read.table(text="Count Group_A Group_B
2 Red One
1 Blue One
1 Green One
5 Red Two
1 Blue Two
2 Red Three
4 Blue Three
2 Green Three
1 Yellow Three
0 Yellow One
0 Green Two
0 Yellow Two", sep=" ", header=TRUE)
```

[image]

For an even closer representation of what you requested;

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Group_B, y=Count, color=Group_A), fill="white", width=0.3, position=position_dodge(width=0.5), stat="identity", lwd=2)     + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("Red"="red", "Blue"="blue", "Green"="green", "Yellow"="yellow")) + theme_bw()
```

[image]